# Daily/Weekly/Monthly Highscores

Tags: php, mysql

I have an online highscores made with php + mysql but it currently shows the All Time highscores, I want to add Daily/Weekly/Monthly to that and I was wondering what would be the best way todo that?

My current thought is to add 3 new tables and then have the data inserted into each of them, and then having a cron which would run at the appropriate times to delete the data from each of the tables.

Is there any better way I could do this?

Another thing, I want to have it so the page would be highscores.php?t=all t=daily, etc. How would I make it so that the page changed the query depending on that value?

Thanks.

Comment: No offence, but your idea is horrible. What you want is whenever you save a score you also save the date and time.

Comment: Are the highscores a result of a sum of other scores? In other words, do you have to update scores frequently adding a value?

Comment: PLEASE INCLUDE YOUR TABLE SCHEMA!!! We have no idea, the table you mention is storing every user cumulative scores per day, or is a score per game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use one table and add a column with the date of the highscore. Then have three different queries for each timespan, e.g.

```
SELECT ... FROM highscores WHERE date>"05-12-2011";
```

If you want to have a generic version without the need to have a fixed date, use this one:

```
SELECT ...
FROM highscores
WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY;
```